# React + Leaflet: how to rotate an array of markers and Rectangle vectors around (i) its center and (ii) one of its corners

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, geometry, rotation

I have created a very simple leaflet map displaying an array of markers as a square which I want to rotate through any angle around its center or relative to its bottom left hand vertex (which is also its origin & position[0][0]).

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-grid-with-markers-ds9yl?file=/src/index.js

I don't wish to rotate individual markers (there's plugins for that) but the entire grid which should maintain its shape with all relative marker spacings remaining the same but with the entire map rotated through any angle. As an added complexity the each marker is rendered within a grid cell which is just a leaflet rectangle but which also needs to maintain its position relative to adjacent cells.

It would be a big bonus to be to be able to apply the transform when generating the grid, but applying the transform to the grid shown is also a great start.

Leaflet already provides path transforms but I need to transform an entire array of markers and their path representations. It looks like a geometry/maths problem but I'm hoping that leaflet already has it covered.

Any help or advice much appreciated.

Comment: I have no idea, but found your question so cool! I would try something with the css transform as explained in [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2Spytldy1o)

Comment: thanks its a great problem for sure. problem with css transforms is it wont map the lat/lng locations which would all need to change relative to the rotation.

Comment: Very interesting question.  I'm fairly sure there is nothing built in to leaflet to do this for you, but it still shouldn't be too hard to accomplish. Before I spend too much time on this, I see you're using react-leaflet v2.  Are you stuck with that, or are you able to upgrade to v3?

Comment: Seeking a react-leaflet 2 solution for now, or even a react-leaflet version independent solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok my friend.  This was not trivial.  But it was fun.

#### [Working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-grid-with-markers-forked-5u5fh)

There is nothing built in to leaflet to make this happen.  I am a big fan of [leaflet-geometryutil](https://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.GeometryUtil/index.html) to do GIS calculations and transformations in leaflet.  While [leaflet-path-transoform](https://github.com/w8r/Leaflet.Path.Transform) exists, I found it to be too narrow in scope for what you need. Rather, let's invent our own wheel.

The absolute simplest way to approach this is to take every coordinate that's involved, and rotate it around a given latlng.  That can be done with leaflet-geometryutil's [`rotatePoint`](https://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.GeometryUtil/global.html#rotatePoint) function.  Note the documentation there is not 100% correct - it takes **4** arguments, the first being the map instance.  So I had to get a `ref` to the map by tagging the `<Map>` component with a ref.

I threw a bit of UI on there so you can manually change the angle, and toggle the point of rotation from the center of the grid to the bottom left corner.  That part is a bit trivial, and you can check out the code in the sandbox.  The most crucial part is being able to rotate every point involved in the grid (squares and markers alike) around a rotation point.  This function does that:

```js
  const rotatePoint = React.useCallback(
    (point) => {
      const { lat, lng } = L.GeometryUtil.rotatePoint(
        mapRef.current.leafletElement,
        L.latLng(point[0], point[1]),
        transformation.degrees,
        L.latLng(axis[0], axis[1])
      );
      return [lat, lng];
    },
    [mapRef, transformation, axis]
  );
```

The `axis` parameter is the rotation origin we want to use.  `transoformation.degrees` is simply the number from a user input to get the nuber of degrees you want to rotate.  I'm not sure how you plan on implementing this (UI vs programatically), but this function enables you to rotate however you want.

When the map is created, we take your `gridBottomLeft` and `gridSize`, and calculate an *initial* grid, called `baseGrid`, and save that to state.  Really this doesn't need to be a state variable, because we don't expect it to change unless `gridBottomLeft` or `gridSize` changes, in which case the component will rerender anyway.  However I kept it as a state var just to keep the same logic you had.  It might *also* make sense to keep it as a state var, because as you see, when you toggle between different rotation origins, things may not behave as you expect, and you may want to reset the `baseGrid` when you toggle rotation origin points.

We keep a *separate* state var for the current state of the grid, `grid`, which is a variation of the `baseGrid`.  When the user changes the degree input, a useEffect is fired, which creates a transofmration of `baseGrid` based on the degree number, and sets it to the `grid` state var:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const rotatedGrid = baseGrid.map((square) => {
      return {
        id: square.id,
        positions: square.positions.map((coord) => {
          return rotatePoint(coord);
        }),
        center: rotatePoint(square.position)
      };
    });
    setGrid(rotatedGrid);
  }, [transformation.degrees, bottomLeft, rotatePoint, baseGrid]);
```

As you can see, what I'm doing is applying our rotation transformation function to all points in the square (renamed to `positions`), as well as the marker's position (renamed `center`).

And voila, the entire grid rotates, along with its markers, around the axis point that you define.

**Note that you were using the `Rectangle` component, with 2 points as bounds to define the rectangle.  This no longer works as you rotate the rectangle, so I converted it to a `Polygon`, with the 4 corners of the square as its `positions` prop.

Also note this ***will not work*** in react-leaflet version 3.  v3 has an absolute ton of breaking changes (which IMO have greatly improved the performance and UX of the library), but the management of refs and changing props is completely different, and as such, will need to be accounted for in v3.  If you have questions about that, comment and I can write a bit more, but this answer is already long.

Comment: amazing! and a UI to control rotation! I'll have to revisit this when i upgrade to v3.  many thanks.